# Which session timeout is used in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-timeout

In ASP.NET you can set the session timeout in several places:

web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login" defaultUrl="Index" timeout="480"/>
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="480"  />
```

And in IIS.

When is which session timeout used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 <forms loginUrl="Login" defaultUrl="Index" timeout="480"/>
```

- is the timeout for the authentication cookie, this means that after login you have 480 minutes till you get redirected to the login page again (if you use sliding expiration it changes a bit).

`<sessionState timeout="480"  />`

- is the timeout for the Session object, so if you have something stored into Session["object"], this will become unavailable after 480 minutes of inactivity.
- if the session timeout is smaller than the login timeout, you could get a `NullReferenceException` when accessing Session["object"].

Comment: Session will expire of after 480 minutes **of inactivity**

Comment: Thnx, and what about the IIS Settings?

Comment: If you modify in IIS, you should get the same changes in the web.config, so you only need to do it in one place, it's the same.

Comment: Which setting will will? The settings in IIS or in the web.config? And are IIS settings also applied to aspx pages?

Comment: The IIS setting (Session State) is the same as <sessionState /> tag in the web.config which are application wide, so they will be applied to all pages. I would go for web.config editing, cause it's easier, and you can just copy/paste settings from a site.

Comment: Thnx,but what happens if IIS is set to 20 and web.config to 30? Which setting is applied?

Comment: In IIS 7, if you set 20 it will overwrite the web.config and if you change it into web.config it will overwrite IIS. It's taking the information from the same place, which is the web.config. In IIS 6 there are some settings that have precedence over web.config, but I didn't found them for an example.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't stated what version of IIS you're using but assuming this is IIS7 or above.

Essentially if you define an explicit value in your config this is what will be used.  In IIS 7 or above setting this value through the IIS console will also update your config file, in IIS 6 it uses the metabase.

Setting the value explictly in your own websites config file will always override that set in IIS unless delegation has been disabled on the feature within applicationHost.config which will throw an error if you set it locally.

You can test this by creating an empty ASP.NET website and deploy to IIS.  You'll see there is no setting for session timeout in it's config file so you'll be using the server setting.  Update the session timeout to a value other than the default in IIS and you'll now see a the specific section has been added to your web.config file so this now the used value.

More info on settings and config management in IIS7+ [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/156/understanding-iis-configuration-delegation/)